# Xcode Organizer: Can't Remove Device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode3.2, xcode-organizer

Using Xcode 3.2.5. I recently connected a coworkers iPhone to my mac to try to install a test build for him to test. After that, I cannot remove his device from my Xcode Organizer. Removing the device will remove it from the device list, but a few minutes later it comes right back without me doing anything.

From another question I found this plist file, and tried manually removing the corresponding entry from it. This doesn't work either. When the device comes back in the Xcode Organizer, it is also re-populated in this plist file:
/Users/kyleh/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist
The entry is under XCKnownRemoteComputers

This is more than just me nit-picking. Sometimes Xcode Organizer will also pop up a warning message when the device is automatically added back. The warning message says "Could not connect to the device." It's a modal dialog box, so I have to click OK in order to continue using the Organizer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have device logs in the special sub-folder where XCode keeps them:
~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/
Xcode may be having trouble deleting them.

You might also try repairing permissions on your Mac with the Disk Utility.

Comment: There were some logs related to that device, but it doesn't look like deleting them helped. After I tried that, Xcode beeped at me with an error message saying "Could not receive a message from the device." And the device is back in the Organizer window...